# RDS 2012 R2 and Remote Desktop Collection: Change "Remote Computer" value

Tags: remote-desktop-services, rds, rdweb

Somewhere along the line, I went down the rabbit hole trying to avoid a SAN certificate and get away with a single certificate that would cover the RDWeb/Gateway/host of the single-server deployment of Remote Desktop Services/RDWeb/Gateway/Session Host (`RDS01`)

Now, I have no idea how I changed the Remote Computer parameter to `remote.contoso.com`, which is the same as the gateway, but cannot be resolved/proxied. **

What's weird is that I'm sure I've fixed this, but after a reboot, it seems to not be persisting.

Looking for canonical ways that this could be changed (Powershell/Registry entr(ies), configuration file(s), etc.) with the end-game being to get it back to "normal": where a simple QuickCollection for Remote Desktop sessions would take the fully-qualified hostname of the Session Host and auto-generate that as the Remote Computer in Remote Desktop shortcut/file on the RDWeb website.

** or its possibly a hairpin NAT issue; not 100% why the single server stack cannot proxy onto itself as that hostname, because I do have split DNS enabled, so you can from another host RDP to `remote.contoso.com` from within the same network as `RDS01`.  Perhaps it's some loopback safety measure?

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be persisting.  ProTip Kids: make notes!

```
Set-RDSessionCollectionConfiguration –CollectionName <your collection> -CustomRdpProperty “use redirection server name:i:1 `n alternate full address:s:RDS01.corp.contoso.com”
```