# Change RDS Remote computer path in .RDP file

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, remote-desktop-services, rds

I have a similar problem as listed here: [RDS 2012 R2 and Remote Desktop Collection: Change "Remote Computer" value](https://serverfault.com/questions/706870/rds-2012-r2-and-remote-desktop-collection-change-remote-computer-value)

I cannot figure out how to use the command listed.

```
Set-RDSessionCollectionConfiguration –CollectionName <your collection> -CustomRdpProperty “use redirection server name:i:1 `n alternate full address:s:RDS01.corp.contoso.com”
```

When looking at this code, can someone explain what servers to put where?

Example:

My DNS name is remote.helper.company.com

My server name is remote.test.company.com (also the name showing up in .RDP file)

I want to set helper to the remote computer name in the .RDP file.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out.

So I needed to just specify the alternate address after full address:s:"name here" full address was a command and I did not realize it.

Also for anyone looking to just update the RDP config file it can be done with the registry, by navigating to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\WindowsNT\CurrentVersion\Terminal Server\